# How do I pass data from a SQL Server to my web Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

I have a web application that I am building and I need to pass data to it from this SQL Server db. I can run the queries and maybe save the output to CSV and then somehow I need to take this File and pass it online but how.

Is there a tool or something I can use to pass this CSV or is there a better approach to passing data from desktop to web.

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db